# how to install software onto ubuntu on hp pavillion

Tags: software-installation

i have just installed Ubuntu, how do I install software from usb onto hp pavillion laptop, running Ubuntu?

thanks

ron devere

Comment: You would have to download the .deb to the usb and use dpkg (and manually resolve dependencies) or configure the usb as a repository.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen or, you know, just run the `deb` and see what it needs.

Comment: If you mean Windows software, then for you, this is going to be impossible or extremely difficult. Use the Ubuntu Software Center to get what you need.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - It will not install if you do not install the dependencies first. Also it is not impossible see http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline and http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-install-deb-packages/

Comment: @bodhi.zazen OK, but we still don't really know what's being asked. Are they asking about Windows programs on Linux? Are they asking about source files on Linux?